# react and redux user authentication store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have two basic questions (dont need anyone to write the code or something, just to see different directions).

When using react, react-router and redux what is the best approach to setup user authentication (using jwt)? I have researched a lot of articles and everyone uses different approach, so it becomes a bit confusing and everyone has different opinion saying other way is wrong etc...

- What way and where is the best place to store user token and all informations related to that?
- How to prevent user from accessing specific routes, what is best approach to do this and where exactly?

Imagine that app is ugins react, react-router for route setup and redux.

Comment: You ll get another person telling his/her opinion about your too broad question. Instead do some more research and only ask questions to clarify specific points of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check [auth wrapper](https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper) - nice solution for your problem.